# render function automatically trigger onClick props function issue in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, es6-modules

In parent component have one child component. In Child component I have one props with click function. In that click function, triggering before click while rendering component. I need to restrict that click function in render. Check below my code...

I have parent component is APP.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { Pagination } from './../Common/index';

class App extends Component {

  handlePageination = (current) => {
    console.log('trigger')
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <main className="main-block">
            <Pagination total={userList.length>0 ? totalCount : 0} range={10} initial={0} rowClick={this.handlePageination} count={currentPageNumber} />
          </main>

    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child component...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import { ORIGIN_PATH } from "./../../../utilities/consts";
import "./Pagination.css";

class Pagination extends Component {

    handlePageClick = (e) => {
        this.props.rowClick(e.selected)
    }

    render() {

        const { range, initial } = this.props;

        let { count, total } = this.props;

        count = count + 10;
        total = parseInt(total, 10);

        if(count===0 && total < 10) {
            count = total
        } else if(count >= total) {
            count = total
        }

        return(
            <div className="pagination-block">
                <p>Showing {count} out of {total} results</p>
                {<ReactPaginate previousLabel={<img src={ORIGIN_PATH + "/images/icons/polygon-prev-icon@3x.png"} alt="Prev" />}
                    nextLabel={<img src={ORIGIN_PATH + "/images/icons/polygon-next-icon@3x.png"} alt="Next" />}
                    breakLabel={<a href="">...</a>}
                    breakClassName={"break-me"}
                    pageCount={total/range}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={range}
                    onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                    initialPage={initial}
                    activeClassName={"active"} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Answer (score 1):

change this in your child component while your using click function inside render user arrow function

```
onPageChange={(e) => this.handlePageClick()}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Pagination` component render

Change

```
 onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
```

To

```
 onPageChange={e => this.handlePageClick(e)}
```

Corrected code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import { ORIGIN_PATH } from "./../../../utilities/consts";
import "./Pagination.css";

class Pagination extends Component {

    handlePageClick = (e) => {
        this.props.rowClick(e.selected)
    }

    render() {

        const { range, initial } = this.props;

        let { count, total } = this.props;

        count = count + 10;
        total = parseInt(total, 10);

        if(count===0 && total < 10) {
            count = total
        } else if(count >= total) {
            count = total
        }

        return(
            <div className="pagination-block">
                <p>Showing {count} out of {total} results</p>
                {<ReactPaginate previousLabel={<img src={ORIGIN_PATH + "/images/icons/polygon-prev-icon@3x.png"} alt="Prev" />}
                    nextLabel={<img src={ORIGIN_PATH + "/images/icons/polygon-next-icon@3x.png"} alt="Next" />}
                    breakLabel={<a href="">...</a>}
                    breakClassName={"break-me"}
                    pageCount={total/range}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={range}
                    onPageChange={e => this.handlePageClick(e)}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                    initialPage={initial}
                    activeClassName={"active"} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pagination;
```