# Function called on loop when setting state inside of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a handlePageClick function called like this inside of my render:

```
onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
```

The functions is:

```
handlePageClick = data => {

    this.setState({
        circleloading: true
    });
    let names = ["page"]
    let values = [data.selected]
    this.updatePublications(names,values)

}
```

For some reason when I do that the function gets called indifinitely? Why?

However when I do the exact same thing inside of other functions that get called on some other time it works fine. So I thought maybe the fact that the function gets triggered by the 'onPageChange' had something to do.

Update, here's my updatePublications function:

```
  updatePublications(names,values){
    let queryParameters = this.generateQueryParametersPackage();
    this.updateQueryParameters(queryParameters,names,values)
    this.pushParameters(names,values);
    let currentComponent = this
    PublicationService.getPublications(queryParameters).then(function (response){
        if(response.status !== StatusCode.OK){
            ErrorService.logError(currentComponent.props,response)
            return;
        }
        currentComponent.setState({
            // other variables ,
            circleloading: false
        })
        currentComponent.updateFilters(queryParameters)
    })
}

updateFilters(queryParameters){
    let currentComponent = this
    PublicationService.getFilters(queryParameters).then(function (response){
        if(response.status !== StatusCode.OK){
            ErrorService.logError(currentComponent.props,response)
            return;
        }
        currentComponent.setState({
            filters: response.data
        })
        currentComponent.hideEmptyFilters(response.data,"locations","filterLocationHeader");
    })
}
```

Comment: What does `updatePublications` do?

Comment: @BrianThompson just updated my question

Comment: Might also be useful to include the code using the loop you reference.

Answer (score -2):

Use arrow function `onPageChange={(e) => this.handlePageClick()}` and it will fire on the event. Without it will fire rerender fire etc. SetState rerenders, function gets called on render.

SetState (in handlePageClick) forces a rerender and then the function will be called again because it's just inline and not in the arrow function.

After some research I have found:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52849831/12694208

> In your Pagination component render
>
> Change

```
 onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
```

to

```
 onPageChange={(e) => this.handlePageClick(e)}
```

&&

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52849820/12694208

> Change this in your child component while your using click function
>   inside render user arrow function

```
onPageChange={(e) => this.handlePageClick()}
```

Both seem to support my case. I would recommend to **use the arrow function**.

If you still have an issue it may be your setState({})

Triggers on page load:

```
componentDidMount() {}
```

Triggers on rerender

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {}
```

Triggers before rerender, returns true, you can return false and it will prevent rerender

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {}
```

To troubleshoot, check these, if the update calls a function that changes a state it will loop indefinitely. If you don't have them inside your components and the arrow function doesn't help you have to provide more details please.

Comment: Mmm that stops the infinite loop but the function stops working properly for some reason. I think it stops receiving data. I wasn't the one who downvoted you though, I just put you one up.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you could already accept the answer as it solves the original issue and we can try to solve your other problem?

Comment: You can try: handlePageClick = (data) => { and (e) => this.handlePageClick(e)

Comment: This will do nothing. `() => this.handlePageClick` is declaring a function that does nothing, as the inner function is never called. `this.handlePageClick` is a function reference, `this.handlePageClick()` is a function call. Even if using a correctly formatted inline function, it will have no difference in effect.

Comment: Basically, your solution addresses a declaration like this `onPageChange={this.handlePageClick()}`. Doing this `onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}` is a correct way to pass a function reference and will only be called when the event is triggered.

Comment: Actually it will make a difference in react, as it renders the dom, without the () => it will call the function instead of waiting on an even as anything in {} is just jsx so basically as if you were writing it in a script tag.

Comment: The setState will rerender the dom, and the whole thing goes around again. May not be an issue in all versions? I can just speak from what I have experienced in the newest reactjs

Comment: I'm sorry but that's just not true. Here is a [link from the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders) talking about this exact thing. You are correct that calling `setState` will rerender, so if it were being called on every render you will have an infinite loop, but passing the function reference is not the cause.

Comment: From your link: How do I pass a parameter to an event handler or callback?
You can use an arrow function to wrap around an event handler and pass parameters:

<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />

Comment: You can, you're correct. Inline arrow functions are not wrong, they just aren't required for most cases. And in this specific case it won't change the outcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206227/discussion-between-lehm-ro-and-brian-thompson).

Comment: I'm still having the same issue (infinite loop) with your proposal. I am also setting state inside componentDidMount but I tried commenting that and the same thing still happens.

Comment: setting state in didMount is no issue, in update it would be. As far es the functions you have provided go, there is not much more that can loop. What does hideEmptyFilters do?